# Use method from other class like native methods?

Tags: java

(newbie in Java) I couldn't find exactly this question on SO. I have project, with two files (phseudo-code):

First Java File (class)

```
public class A  {
    public void xyz() { System.out.println("hello");}
}
```

Second Java File (class)

```
public class B Extends ZZZZZ {
    public void callme() { 
         xyz();    // <----------------- I want to call in this way, but It cant be done like this.
    }
}
```

How to make `xyz()` to call successfully (like as if was defined inside `b()` class natively !!).

p.s. again, I don't want to call it with classname in front, like this:

```
a.xyz();
```

Comment: *"calling this shows error"* what error?

Comment: also: is this your original code this the unknown class `string` or is your shift key unreliable?

Comment: `new` is not a good name for a variable...

Comment: You should learn about OOP, how classes and instances relate, maybe `static` is what you are looking for. Your question is unclear as of now.

Comment: `xyz` is always going to be associated with the type `A` so you either call it on an instance of `A` or you make it static and call it on the type: `A.xyz();`. The only way your code would work is if `B` was a subclass of `A` (for example if `ZZZZZ` extended `A`.) - given that you fix all of the syntax errors.

Comment: *"p.s. I dont want like this:

`A new=New A();
new.xyz();`"* why? ist it just your feelings being hurt or is there a business requirement?

Comment: Your `xyz` function doesn't return anything, so this shouldn't compile. Are you sure the error is at runtime?

Comment: @pushkin This actually won't compile for a lot of reasons :D

Comment: @Keiwan Yes, you're right :)

Comment: If that method would be static solution would be using static import. But 
since it is not, it suggests that it should be bounded with some instance of A class, so it should take into account its state (fields). If such instance will not exist then method can't work properly so you need to provide it. Anyway for now your question looks like [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Neither of the three code snippets would compile, either use actual pseudo-code and mark it as pseudo-code or post actual java code, `string` starts with a capital `S`, `Extends` starts with a lower case `e`, `new` is a reserved keyword, `New` is not the keyword for creating new instances.

Comment: Not a native method, technically the term is free function.

Comment: Guys, thanks, you are all right... I have just typed this pseudo-code in SO editor, so many grammar/syntax errors could be due to fast typing..  My main objective is the answer to question (and seems some answers fit me). thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay several possibilities:

## Instantiate A:

```
A a=new A();
a.xyz();
```

(you do not want this)

## Heredity:

```
public class B extends A {...}
```

and

```
public class A extends ZZZZZ{...}
```

so you can still extend ZZZZZ;

## Interface:

```
public interface A{...}

public class B extends ZZZZZ implements A{...}
```

## Static Method:

```
public class A{
  public static void xyz()
  {
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
}

public class B{
  public void callme()
  {
      A.xyz());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of instance methods, like `xyz` is in this, is that you are using the state of an instance of `A` in the method, without having to pass that instance as an argument like this:

```
... String xyz(A thisInstance, ...) {...}
```

Instead you use:

```
A thisInstance = ...;
thisInstance.xyz(...);
```

That's why you need an instance of `A`, because it is practically an argument to the function.

---

However, if you don't *need* an instance of `A`, you can make the method static:

```
static String xyz(...) {...}
```

Then you can call it without passing an instance of `A`:

```
A.xyz(...);
```

You can use a static import so that you don't have to write `A`:

```
import static A.xyz;

...

xyz(...);
```

Comment: is there a way, to import all functions from `A` like that (not individual methods from `A`)

Comment: @T.Todua Yes, you can use a wildcard: `import static A.*;`

Comment: the last method doesnt work... it shows `cannot fidn symbol method xyz()`

Comment: @T.Todua It works fine for me, although it doesn't work if `A` is in the default package, but it gives a different error.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
class A {
    public void xyz() {
         System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
class ZZZZZ extends A{

}
 class B extends ZZZZZ {
    public void callme() {
        xyz();// <----------------- calling this shows error
    }
}
```

Comment: please, post them in one answer, instead of many answers.. thanks anyway, but seems not solution, `ZZZZZ` is already registered class of project.